# single tap hide show buttons,iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I have small query, which is related to single tap.

I have 3 buttons, which are intially hidden.
One a single tap on view, i want to show those buttons and on tapping again ,those should button should be  hidden.This is not double tap gesture, its a single tap gesture only.

something like this

```
- (void)handleSingleTap:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer {
    // single tap action
    NSLog(@"Single Tap"); if(first time tap) { show } else if(second time tap){ hide }

}
```

So its should be like,
if i tap once, it should show, if tap again, it should hide, and again on tapping,it should show and .............

please suggest.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

declare a `static` variable to control if it is the first tap or not, like this:

```
- (void)handleSingleTap:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer {
    static BOOL firstTap = YES;
    // single tap action
    NSLog(@"Single Tap"); 
    if(firstTap) { 
        // show
        firstTap = NO; 
    } else { 
        // hide 
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

if you want to change the value of the `hidden` property on each tap then just use:

```
yourButton.hidden = !yourButton.hidden;
```

Comment: sry if my question was confusing.I edit it a bit.Show/hide should work on each tap,not on first and second tap.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, if you are using button, then you dont need to implement Single tap Gesture on it. 
button itself provides click event.

beware once you hide the button how will you get tap event on it?? that screw up my mind..!